# Not able to login angular application with nodejs from mobile devices

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mobile, https

I have an application that I created that runs Angular 6, NodeJS, Express.
Currently, the app is deployed and works without error on desktops & laptop browsers. Whenever I try to log in over a mobile device (smartphone, tablet, etc.) and these also occur with only some mobile devices the connection times out. I have used remote device debugging via Chrome but it is slow, unresponsive and pretty much useless.

```
 this.dmsCallService.loginEmp(data).subscribe(result => {
  if(result){
    console.log("result in node response",result)

    this._snackBar.open(result.msg, 'Close', {
      duration: 1000,
      verticalPosition: 'top', // 'top' | 'bottom'
      horizontalPosition: 'end', //'start' | 'center' | 'end' | 'left' | 'right'
      panelClass: ['red-snackbar'],
    });

    localStorage.setItem('LoginData', JSON.stringify(result.info))
    sessionStorage.setItem('loginData', JSON.stringify(result.token));
    sessionStorage.setItem('menuData', JSON.stringify(result.menudata));
    sessionStorage.setItem('designation', JSON.stringify(result.designation));
    sessionStorage.setItem('id', JSON.stringify(result.id));
  }
  //this.myRoute.navigate(["dashboard"])

  console.log("designation for login",result.info.Designation)
  if (result.info.Designation == 'Student') {
      setTimeout((router: Router) => {
        this.myRoute.navigate(['student']);
      }, 1000);
  }


  if (result.info.Designation == 'Admin') {
    setTimeout((router: Router) => {
      this.myRoute.navigate(['admin']);
    }, 1000);
}

}, err => {
  this._snackBar.open('Login Error', 'error', {
      duration: 2000,
      verticalPosition: 'top', // 'top' | 'bottom'
      horizontalPosition: 'end', //'start' | 'center' | 'end' | 'left' | 'right'
      panelClass: ['red-snackbar'],
    });
 // this.isLoading = false;

});
```

Comment: CODE Pleas, Write code hare.

Comment: this.dmsCallService.loginEmp(data).subscribe(result => {
      
      console.log("designation for login",result.info.Designation)
      if (result.info.Designation == 'Student') {
          setTimeout((router: Router) => {
            this.myRoute.navigate(['student']);
          }, 1000);
      }


      if (result.info.Designation == 'Admin') {
        setTimeout((router: Router) => {
          this.myRoute.navigate(['admin']);
        }, 1000);
    }
      
    }, err => {
      
        });
 

    });